# bleeding radiator without access to the bleeder valve

Tags: heating, radiator, old-house

I've got a cast iron radiator where the end with the bleeder valve is shoved up against a wall. Is there any other way to bleed a radiator? Supply and return pipes are at top and bottom of the opposite side. What if I loosened the nut on the top pipe?

Comment: is this a steam or hot water system